# Swift: bug to get and read the data from the database sqlite

Tags: swift, sqlite

I do not understand why when I try to recover data from the database it puts me "45" instead of the first two letters, here my code and picture:

```
func getData() -> Array<User>{

    var data : Array<User> = Array()

    //this is our select query
    let queryString = "SELECT * FROM \(table_name)";

    //statement pointer
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?

    //preparing the query
    if (sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK){
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
    }

    //traversing through all the records
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
        /*
         * On recupere les donnees pour les rentrer dans des variables, le deuxieme parametre cest la colonne
         * sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0) pour recuperer un INT
         * String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)) //pour recuperer un string
         */
        let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)

        //adding values to list
        let user: User = User(name: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)),
                              adress: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)),
                              note: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 6)),
                              infoSup: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4)),
                              city: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4)),
                              phone: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)),
                              countryCode: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 10)),
                              mail: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 8)),
                              codeZ: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 9)));

        print(user.getName());

        user.setId(id: Int(id)); //On configure le ID manuellement
        user.setDate(date: Int64(String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 7)))!)
        data.append(user); //On rentre
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbbvG.png)

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. List the actual fields you want in the order you want them. This will ensure that the column numbers you use in the `sqlite3_column_xxx` functions match the columns you query. Also note the column numbers start with 0.

Comment: the first column it is the ID in index 0